# change class on different li's

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have 18 images that gets displayed like 6 images in each row. I want to assign different class to every second last and last image in a row.
eg :-

```
1    2    3    4    5    6
7    8    9    10   11   12
13   14   15   16   17   18
```

Here class should be different for the  `5   6    11    12    17    18`

I am able to make equation for this as leaving 5   6

it could be `5n + (n-1)          6n`
starting from n=2

```
   5(2) + (2-1)    6(2)  =    11    12
   5(3) + (3-1)    6(3)  =    17    18
```

I am not sure how to implement this using jquery.
AS 5   6   should be as it is and then equation for 11,12,17,18 and starting n=2

```
<li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="images/img14.jpg" alt="" width="136" height="136" /><em class="popup"> <strong class="arrow"></strong><strong class="title">Sponsor Name Here</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur edt adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim enim ut co. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur bel adipiscing elit nullam digniss</em></a></li>
```

In em I want to add class popup-left

Comment: That's nice, but we need to see the **HTML**

Comment: Maybe you should post the html, that will be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You don't need jQuery for this.**

The following selector will apply the styles you require:

```
li:nth-child(6n) img, li:nth-child(6n-1) img
{
    /* styles here */
}
```

[**See Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/FJLfz/)

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood (and assuming you have `li` elements)

```
$('li:nth-child(6n+4)').addClass('class1');
$('li:nth-child(6n+5)').addClass('class2');
```

or just define that selectors as straight css (but in this case it won't work on `IE<9`)

```
li:nth-child(6n+4) {
  ...
}

li:nth-child(6n+5) {
  ...
}
```

if needed change `li` with your real element (`img`, `p` or anything else)

Comment: If the images are inside LI element as the title suggests then this won't work